# Vue Router not matching a url with multiple dynamic values

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to add a nested url to my routes. So far, every route works fine except for the last one (see code below).

I also tried nesting the urls (using the `children` property), but was unsuccessful with that, and I don't think that's the approach I want to take here anyway, since I want to use an entirely separate component, and not nest the `<router-view>`s.

Any suggestions for what I should do? I'm not even sure how to debug. The Vue dev tools just show a `<RouterView>` component, with one prop: `name: "default"`.

Here is my routes.js file:

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

import Search from './views/Search';
import FoodItem from './views/FoodItem';
import NutrientCategory from './views/NutrientCategory';
import NutrientDetail from './views/NutrientDetail';

let routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: Search
  },
  {
    path: '/:id',
    component: FoodItem
  },
  {
    path: '/nutrients/:slug',
    component: NutrientCategory
  },
  {
    path: '/nutrients/:slug/:nutrient-slug',
    component: NutrientDetail
  }
]

export default new VueRouter({
  routes,
  linkActiveClass: 'active',
  scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
    return { x: 0, y: 0 }
  }
});
```

Comment: Try adding a `key` attribute to the `<router-view>` component. ie. `<router-view :key="$route.fullPath" />`

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you try to use the `minus` sign as the parameter name:

```
/nutrients/:slug/:nutrient-slug
```

But the regular expression from the [`path-to-regexp`](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#advanced-matching-patterns) package for parsing the path-pattern uses the `\w` character classe as the name-pattern:

```
\w+ matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
```

So use underscore instead of minus:

```
/nutrients/:slug/:nutrient_slug
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/fhrekL25/ ]

Comment: Hi have you found out way to fix?